# Returning string with brackets around it

Tags: nsstring

I have a method that returns a NSString * successfully.

I want to have the string returned with brackets round it.

ie. Currently the method returns something like @"myString" and I want

@"(myString)". How can I stick a bracket at the start and another at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[stringWithFormat](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat:) should do it;

```objc
NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", myString];
```